# Automatically update UiLabels based on values in array in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UiTableView with labels in  each row showing the value of a property of an item in an underlying array of objects.

```
class Things {
    var number: Double = 0
}

var things: [Things] = []
```

and

```
class thingsVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var thingsTableView: UITableView!

    // etc etc
}
```

I want to know what the best way is of telling the label to update every time the property is changed. I know I can trigger this with `didSet()`

Should I use a delegate? Should I use NSNotificationCenter? I don't know how to reliably reference the TableView from the `Things` object.

The change could happen from anywhere and at any time in the app, but I always need to update the same TableView with the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more than 3 options, I will cover these which you want probably most to use.

1. Use KVO -> I personally think this is the best solution to this.
2. Use Delegates -> This is still popular solution and I suggest it right after the KVO.
3. Use Notifications -> I wouldn't do it, generally Use of notification is not too good in Swift to do, you can get in trouble if you do not use them properly.
4. Use RxSwift + RxCocoa or ReactiveCocoa to this -> This would be awesome if you would like to have your whole app Reactive, which you should consider if you are subscribing to lots of changes.

In the end the KVO wins because if you need to set it anywhere from the app, that's the thing you want to use.

Comment: Thank-you :) I'm checking out KVO now. I've just added to the question explaining how I don't know how to reference the ViewController and TableView from the object but I don't think that matters to KVO. Thanks

Comment: @Sean check it out :) in Swift 4 it is just super awesome.

Comment: Wow. It's beautiful. :(). THANKS

Comment: Care to explain why this is not accepted answer anymore? :D I don't mind, I just wanna know to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need call **NSNotificationCenter** or use **delegate**. You can only use didSet and reloadData:

```
var things: [Things] = []
{
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. :) I've just added to the question explaining how I don't know how to reference the ViewController and TableView from the object.

Comment: Ohhhhhh, in that case the  @Dominik Bucher 's answer is right, the KVO is the best way.